# Clicking on Buy now Button in Aliexpress Python Selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to Click on Buy now Button in Aliexpress Python Selenium

for example

```
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000001810642.html


clikcononbuynows= driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#root > div > div.product-main > div > div.product-info > div.product-action > span.buy-now-wrap > button')
clikcononbuynows.click()
```

[image]

Also one more issue I want to click on the Search button and write something like "android cable"
but it doesn't click
the code I am using for that is

```
search = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#search-key')
search.send_keys('android data cable')
```

[image]

Kindly Let me know What I am missing and help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To type in the search box and click on Search:

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "search-key").send_keys("android data cable")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='header-search-btn']//button[@type='submit']").click()
```

To click on Buy Now option:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='product-action']//button[text()='Buy Now']").click()
```

Updated per user query:
[Search Button Clicked Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMx87.png)

Full code for Search button: Note the time delays:

```
driver.get("https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000001810642.html")
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "search-key").send_keys("android data cable")
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='header-search-btn']//button[@type='submit']").click()
```

Please use `webdriverwait` instead of `time.sleep`

Comment: driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='header-search-btn']//button[@type='submit']").click()
This one is not Working

Comment: Buy now Button Also not Working it throughs an Exception

Comment: @MuazmaTech For Buy button, you must select the options prior to clicking on Buy. Did you do that?
Example: `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//img[@alt='Red']").click()`   `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='sku-property-text'])[3]").click()`

Comment: Did you use time delays after hitting the url? If so, the search code works. Check out the updated answer. I have added the full code leading to search click.

Comment: Yes it is Working Directly thank you !! but when account is logged in and I try some different product it doesn't work maybe the Button XPath is changed for them